# Нужна ли запятая в фразе "видя в каком состоянии"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Андрей решил не беспокоить Олега, видя(,) в каком состоянии тот находится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Да.** *Видя* — одиночное деепричастие, и оснований для непостановки запятой нет.